# JavaScript named sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting, anonymous-function

I was wondering if it's possible to pass a named function to Array.sort(). I'm trying to do something like the logic below but obviously it complains about `a` not being defined.

```
if (iWantToSortAscending) {
    myArray.sort(sortAscending(a, b));
} else {
    myArray.sort(sortDescending(a, b));
}

// my lovely sort functions
function sortAscending(a, b) {
    ...
    sorty worty
    ...
}

function sortDescending(a, b) {
    ...
    sorty worty differently
    ...
}
```

Obviously I could get the code to work like below, and it does, but I'd rather not be using anonymous functions for the sake of readability and debugging.

```
if (iWantToSortAscending) {
    myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
        ...
        sorty worty
        ....
    }
} else {
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sure is, but you have to reference the function, not call it, and arguments are passed automagically

```
myArray.sort(sortAscending);
```

whenever you add parentheses and arguments to a function, it's called immediately.
When you want it to be called by another function, for instance as a callback in `sort()`, you reference it, and leave the parentheses out.

Answer (score 4):

Think "what is my program doing?"

```
myArray.sort(sortAscending(a, b));
```

What does it do? It tries to call `myArray.sort` with result of expression `sortAscending(a,b)`. First of all, `a` and `b` aren't defined, so it throws (`ReferenceError`).
But what if `a` and `b` are defined? Result of expression `sortAscending(a,b)` wouldn't be a function.

To get things working, you have to use code `myArray.sort(sortAscending);` - it passes a function as argument.